# Как создать и удалить директорию вот тут `/storage/emulated/0/MyApp/MyDir`

Tags: android

Есть путь

```
Constans.DIR_PATH = "/storage/emulated/0/MyApp/MyDir"
```

Для создания я использую вот такой метод

```
private void createMainModelsDir()
{
    new File(Constans.DIR_PATH).mkdirs();
}
```

И для удаления вот такой

```
public static boolean deleteEmptyDirs(File dir)
{
    return dir.delete();
}
```

Но почему то ни один не другой не работают...

Вот эти пермищены есть

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Что не так?

**EDIT**

Вот тут я пробую создать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это получается просто в корне карты есть папка и в этой папке нужно еще сделать/удалить папку?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko ну да, наверное нельзя там капаться из приложения, да?

Comment: /storage/emulated/0 - разве этот путь не общий? это по-моему корень карты память и доступ у вас должен быть

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko нет, это корень самого устройства. Добавил скриншот в вопрос

Comment: добавил ответ, но интересно какую цель вы преследуете?

Comment: У меня есть приложение которое должно создать папку в которую юзер должен сложить файлы...

Comment: что значит сложить? в процессе работы с приложением у пользователя появляются файлы?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko нет, просто юзер открывает устройство и копирует файлы в папку. Руками...

Comment: а в чем смысл такого действия? можно сделать селектор файлов просто и все, разве так не проще?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko да, но юзер должен сложить в папку около 1000 файлов с общим размером >2Гб... То есть в любом случае он должен эти файлы как то положить на устройство... Так пусть сразу складывает их в папку коротую я "должен автоматически создать" ( и которая пока не хочет создаваться)

Comment: довольно сложно для понимания то что у вас происходит, откуда берутся файлы, он их откуда берет, подключает устройство к пк и кидать?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko ну да, подключаешь к компу и закидываешь в папку. Но не в этом дело. Дело в том, что есть локациия где нужно создать папку, а она не создаётся там.

Answer (score 1):

Вот как я думаю можно создать папку:

```
   File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyApp");

 if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
    Log.d("App", "failed to create directory");
}
}
```

все должно получится, так как я у себя тоже пользуюсь таким способом. А вот так удаляется папка вместе со всем содержимым:

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"Dir_name_here"); 
if (dir.isDirectory()) 
{
    String[] children = dir.list();
    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
    {
       new File(dir, children[i]).delete();
    }
}
```

Указываете где и как создать папку и все :)

Comment: При создании я постоянно попадаю сюда `failed to create directory` ... Странно...

Answer (score 0):

По созданию вот вариант:

```
// Check or create directory
File externalStorage = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyApp/MyDir");

if (!externalStorage.exists()) {
    externalStorage.mkdirs();
}
```

Попробуйте так удалять:

```
public static boolean deleteEmptyDirs(File dir)
{

    try {
        if (dir.listFiles() != null) {
            for (File imgFile : dir.listFiles()) {

                imgFile.delete();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("IMAGECLEANER", "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return dir.delete();
}
```

Покуда я помню то сначала нужно удалить файлы из папки, а только потом пустую папку.